# .htaccess with multiple slashes on the condition

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache-config

I am trying to implement clean URL with the help of `.htaccess` in my project.

I got a `404` when i implimented a condition with **multiple condition strings** like `keyword1/keyword2/param`

*all other conditions like* `RewriteRule ^home  index.php [L,NC]` *works fine*

My file structure be like

```
/subdirectory/
            |-.htaccess
            |-index.php
            |-edit-user.php
            |-new-user.php
```

my desired clean url is

```
mysite.com/subdirectory/user/edit/10
```

and it should translated into

```
mysite.com/subdirectory/edit-user.php?id=10
```

Some of the closest solutions i tried so far (but no luck)

```
RewriteRule (.*)/user/edit/([0-9]+)$ edit-user?id=$1 [L,NC]


RewriteBase /user/
RewriteRule ^user\/edit\/([0-9]+)$ edit-user.php?id=$1 [L,NC]
```

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> RewriteRule (.*)/user/edit/([0-9]+)$ edit-user?id=$1 [L,NC]
> ```

Since the `.htaccess` file is inside the `/subdirectory` then you would need to write the directive like this:

```
RewriteRule ^user/edit/(\d+)$ edit-user.php?id=$1 [L]
```

And remove any `RewriteBase` directive.

`\d` is simply a shorthand character class for `[0-9]`.

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against the relative URL-path (no slash prefix). That is relative to the directory that contains the `.htaccess` file. You were also missing the `.php` extension on the filename you are rewriting to. You do not need the `NC` flag unless you really do want to allowed a mixed-case request, but that opens you up to potential "duplicate content" which would need to be resolved in other ways.

> ```
> RewriteBase /user/
> RewriteRule ^user\/edit\/([0-9]+)$ edit-user.php?id=$1 [L,NC]
> ```

Actually, you are very close here, but the `RewriteBase` directive would have caused this to fail. The sole purpose of the `RewriteBase` directive is to override the directory-prefix that is added back on relative path *substitutions*. The `RewriteBase` directive sets the "URL-path" (as opposed to filesystem path) that is added back.

So, in this example, `RewriteBase /user/` would result in the request being rewritten to `/user/edit-user.php?id=10` (relative to the root), which is clearly wrong based on the file structure you posted.

Without the `RewriteBase` defined then the directory-prefix is added back, which results in the rewrite being relative to the directory containing the `.htaccess` file.

Also, there's no need to backslash-escape slashes since there are no slash delimiters to the regex. (The *spaces* that surround the argument are the delimiters.)

> all other conditions like `RewriteRule ^home  index.php [L,NC]` works fine

Careful with this, as this will also match `/homeanything` and `/home/something` etc.

Comment: First of all, Thank you for the time you have taken to answer my question in a very clear way.
Unfortunately, that doesn't work for me
my .htaccess code here.

`Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews`
`RewriteEngine On`

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`

`RewriteRule ^home  index.php [L,NC]`
`RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC]`
`RewriteRule ^user/edit/(\d+)$ edit-user?id=$1 [L]`

`#Prevent viewing of .htaccess file`
`<Files .htaccess>`
`order allow,deny`
`deny from all`
`</Files>`

`#Prevent directory listings`
`Options All -Indexes`

Comment: Note: I have a .htaccess file in the route directory with basic codes for adding .php extension, preventing access to .htaccess file and prevent directory listing (in the same way given in the above code).

Sorry for the formatting in the previous comment since I couldn't find a way to put it in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

**Finally** found the issue.

My `.htaccess` was

```
RewriteRule ^home  index.php [L,NC] RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC] 
RewriteRule ^user/edit/(\d+)$ edit-user?id=$1 [L]
```

*(1st line to add `.php` to anything that comes in, and the 2nd line to convert the desired URL I needed)*

What happened here is, when I try to access the URL `mysite.com/subdirectory/user/edit/10`

The first rule converts that into `mysite.com/subdirectory/user/edit/10.php` instead of `mysite.com/subdirectory/edit-user.php?id=10`

This causes the 404 error.

Now I changed the order and the new .htaccess file looks like,

```
RewriteRule ^admin/edit/(\d+)$ edit-admin.php?aid=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC]
```

So, when a URL comes in, it will check into all other rules before its matches against the last rule(which appends .php) and translate into the desired result.

**Lesson learned:** Order matters a lot in .htaccess